# Confusion about usefulness of Web Workers

Tags: javascript, image-processing, web-worker

I have 4 image elements.

I load an image(s) using:

```
myImg1.src="callGenericHandler.ashx?uidfor#1=" + uid;
myImg2.src="callGenericHandler.ashx?uid=for#2" + uid;
myImg3.src="callGenericHandler.ashx?uid=for#3" + uid;
myImg4.src="callGenericHandler.ashx?uid=for#4" + uid;
```

I know when to call these in my code because I am also using signalR. When I receive a message from my server I know to reset/recall the src of a particular image.

So, I was looking at using WebWorkers to quicken loading times

Now, I know how it works but as soon as 1 web worker has finished I have to in effect 'copy/move' the image that was loaded in the  web-worker to rejoin the main thread.  So what is the point of using this for images as it will actually increase processing time?

Is using webworkers a bad thing for on-demand image processing?

Comment: I would consider it a logic issue as far as *"Now, when my server is busy the client can get 'bogged' down with these calls."*. I don't see how adding a webworker would really change what's happening here, since the problem is network not processing.

Comment: @kevin Hi Kevin thanks for you post.  I may have 4 images that are ready to be loaded almost all at the same time if I was using a desktop app I would create threads. But as I am using JavaScript I cannot. But I can use a web worker. But, after the image has loaded the web worker would have to copy the image back to calling code? Is that not correct?  That was my question really. I appreciate what you say about logic of it all and I can indeed put some 'throtterling' in.  I just really wanted to know the useful of image loading using a webworker.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "bogged down"?

Comment: WebWorkers do help with image *processing*, not with image *loading* (except for sjax requests maybe that can simplify some code)

Comment: Hi, i think I need to edit my question to focus on the image loading via webworker regardless of throtterling :)

Comment: @bergi Thank you. That was the clarity I was missing.  Many thanks :)